# Connecting to EC2 AWS times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sftp, filezilla

It was working before on the same settings but now it just times out. I've tried it on FileZilla and Cyberduck.

```
Protocol: SFTP
Host: (public DNS)
Logon Type: Ask for password
User: Ubuntu
SSH file attached its .pem file
```

On the AWS status, the instance state is running.

Comment: Did you confirm that the instance ip hasn't changed?

Comment: You need to give some more information about the issue. Have you tried simple ssh? Any changes to security groups or ssh config file?

Comment: A timeout normally indicates that there is no network connectivity. Please Edit your question to show the Security Group inbound rules associated with the instance. It is also possible that the public IP address can change if the instance is stopped and started, so check that it is still current.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! The public DNS changed and I didn't notice until the comments pointed it out

Comment: If you wish to avoid this from happening in future, you can **create an Elastic IP address**, which is a static IP address. You can then associated it with the instance and the public IP address will not change.